# How to make LLVM-3.7 default on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: haskell, raspberry-pi, llvm, raspbian

I'm on the default Raspbian OS and `sudo apt-get install llvm` seems to install `llvm-3.5` with a bunch of soft links (like `llvm-link` pointing to `llvm-link-3.5`) However, I'd like to install `llvm-3.7` and have it treated as the "default" LLVM by the system. I've tried fiddling around with `update-alternatives` but couldn't get it to work. Help will be appreciated.

PS: I need 3.7 over 3.5 because of https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11190

Comment: I don't understand your PS. What version of ghc are you using?

Comment: GHC 7.10.3 It seems to behave weirdly with LLVM 3.5 and the Trac issue mentions some important patches that are available from LLV 3.5.2 onwards.

Comment: For GHC 7.10 you need LLVM 3.5.2 exactly, not a later major version. The LLVM assembly changes in a non-backwards compatible way with just about every major version of LLVM. You can use LLVM 3.7 with GHC 8.

Comment: In that case, do you know how to install LLVM 3.5.2 on R-Pi and make that the default?